# Crop a part of an image ( javafx )

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to overflow so I apologize in advance if I am not precise enough.

1. During a class project I have to make a tanquin game in javafx. I must be able to cut an image into x part in order to insert them then in an Arraylist with an id and the part of the image. But I have the error attached here.

   [image: screenshot of my error]
2. I guess the reader is null and that the error is related to that. But I don't know how to fix it.
3. I never used those library so i dont know how to use them.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelReader;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Image image = new Image("https://scontent-yyz1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c180.0.720.720a/s640x640/75272157_461406551233157_7963091763107249286_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-yyz1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=eu-9K8wyx6oAX9H695F&oh=429cc1e6dcec03badc9aac439b6b8ac0&oe=5EAD8EA3", true);

        PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();
        WritableImage newImage = new WritableImage(reader,100,100,100,100);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(newImage);

        HBox hbox = new HBox(imageView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 640, 640);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your question, and include the exception’s full stack trace in the question itself, as text in a code-formatted block.  Images are hard to read, impossible to search or copy, and prevent sight impaired SO users from helping you.  Similarly, include your code in your question as text, not as an image.

Comment: Nelson, welcome to stackoverflow!

For your problem, keep in mind that the PixelReader will return null in several cases, such as problems in your path or image not fully loaded, as per the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#getPixelReader

I think your problem is with the URL in the Image constructor, but it's hard to reproduce.

Also please follow the SO guidelines to improve your question writing, as this may greatly increase your chances of obtaining answers. This link might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I succeeded by replacing the image with an image from my disk. And instead of putting image directly in the pixelreader I use an inputstream method. Thank you for your help. Code :         InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("src/res/image1.jpg"));
        Image image = new Image(is);
        PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();